# Laravel: does exists a equivalent of var_export($var, True) helper?

Tags: php, laravel

Often becomes handy to debug out the dump of a variable

Laravel's

```
dd($v); 
dump($v);
```

are so useful.

I wonder if there's such a function that dumps the variable as a returned string instead of printing it out.

Like in php :

```
var_export($var, TRUE)
```

Note: I'm asking for a specific Laravel function not the built in PHP function , var_dump, var_export or print_r. I already know about it.

Comment: Have you looked into [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)? `$string = print_r($var, TRUE)`

Comment: While not an answer to the specific question...have you used xdebug? It's so worth it to take a few minutes to get it installed/configured.

Comment: What kind of var do you want to debug exactly, and why don't you want to print'em out?

Comment: Thinking  about logging.... or alerting (via some channel) errors, exception...you would build strings of errors. Yep xdebug good way to have instant inspection of objects.

Comment: No such function exists for Laravel. You could look into the source of `dd()` and try to come up with your own. Also, if logging is the end goal, have you tried passing your data (whatever you were going to pass as a param to `dd()` in an array as the second parameter to `Log::info()`? See https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#logging "Contextual Information"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pre` tag to format your output

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

*Edited*

If you want to store the dump in a variable, I guess you can do like below

Import `use Illuminate\Support\Debug\Dumper;`

```
$data = User::all(); // change it according to your requirement

array_map(function ($data) {
    (new Dumper)->dump($data);
}, func_get_args());
```

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear in my question but I'm asking for a Laravel specific function. Not a PHP. Secondly I want a function that stores the dump as a string in a variable not  that prints the var structure on STDOutput.

Comment: updated with the actual content from `dd()` function

Comment: Good idea to look at the source of `dd()`, but I think that'll still print the result, whereas the OP wants to assign the output to a variable.

Comment: @koalaok the `dump()` function that ships with Laravel is actually part of Symphony2 component. You may [alter it's behavior to dump into a string](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced.html#dumpers) instead of printing output.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything, so I resort to this:

```
    $string = var_export($data, true);
    Log::info($string);
```